# Parenthesis possible combination patterns

Tags: c++

I come across the parenthesis combination coding problem and one of the possible solution search found as below,

```
void Ans(int open,int close,string output)
{
    if(open == 0 && close == 0)
    {
        cout<<output<<"\n";
        return;
    }

    if(open)
    Ans(open-1,close,output+"(");

    if(open<close)
    Ans(open,close-1,output+")");
}

int main()
{
    int n=2;

    Ans(n,n,"");
    return 0;
}
```

Problem: How above code call the second parenthesis pattern. I could unnderstand the first line,
if n=2 or more then how it trigger the second line of pattern.

---edit
Like, n=2, output is,

(())
()()

now, first line `(())` make sense the call stack but, how initiate the second line pattern combination as, its already `return` while printing first line  (()) `cout<<output<<"\n";
            return;`

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to solve? The description of the problem is a bit unclear, at least to me.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 looks like `c++` by the usage of `cout`.

Comment: Are you asking how it calls `Ans(open,close-1,output+")");`? That would be when `if ( open < close )` is true … Have you tried explaining the code to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: please be more descriptive. What is the "parenthesis combination problem"? What is "the second parenthesis pattern" in the code?

Comment: Is the if(open) that you don't understand ? if open == 0, the code within if(open) is not executed

Comment: added edit comments

Comment: add return; at the end of your if(open) if you don't want these other paranthesis

Comment: @dsi Write a small program, single step using the debugger, watch variables and inspect the path the code is taking.  That is how every programmer gets to understand how a code "runs".

Comment: Have you tried a counting algorithm?  Set counter to 0.  Reading of `'('` increments the counter.  Reading of `')'` decrements the counter.  Simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have recursive calls.

- `Ans(2, 2, "");` calls only `Ans(1, 2, "(");`
- `Ans(1, 2, "(");` would call `Ans(0, 2, "((");` (first pattern) and `Ans(1, 1, "()");` (second pattern).
- `Ans(0, 2, "((");` would call `Ans(0, 1, "(()");` and recursively `Ans(0, 0, "(())");` (displayed)
- `Ans(1, 1, "()");` would call `Ans(0, 1, "()(");` and recursively `Ans(0, 0, "()()");` (displayed)

Comment: Thanks for details. I missed the bottom up second stack call Ans(1, 1, "()"). so two times it call print option.

Comment: Is it fall under, time complexity -    2(n) ?